# Horizontal image slider 1px content persists occasionally in Ipad even after the scrolling content ends

Tags: javascript, css, ios, web, frontend

When we are scrolling to the `left/right` a `1px` width of the last image occasionally appears on the right edge of the bottom slider. see the attached screenshot. Even though the slider works without any issues occasional we can see the right side 1px when we scroll slowly. This only happens on iPad.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Please provide your code so others can replicate the issue.